# How can I create a dictionary within another dictionary with count capability?

Tags: python, dictionary, count

I have a set of files, in which I want to extract special names and count the name in each file. I want my final result to be two dictionaries like below:

```
{ID1:{sam:1,maj:5, tif:7, paul:1},ID2={maj=4,bib=5},..}
```

I wrote the below code for that:

```
val={}   
for m in result:    
    f= open(path+m[1]+'.txt', 'r')
    for line in f:
        search_str= "my_name"
        if line.startswith(search_str):            
            linename = line.split(' ',2)[1].strip()
            key= get_name_part(linename)                       
            val[key] = val.get(key, 0) + 1 

    maindict[m[0]]=val
```

Where m[0] is the 'fileID'(key for my big dictionary) and m[1]= is the file that have to be open.

When running the code, my inner dictionary is always the same but only the keys of the outer dictionary differs.like this:

```
{ID1:{sam:1,maj:5, tif:7, paul:1},ID2={sam:1,maj:5, tif:7, paul:1},..}
```

Anyone have any idea how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never create a *new* `val` dictionary, you just keep updating the one you created before the loop. Create a new one for each `ID`:

```
maindict = {}
for m in result:
    val = maindict.setdefault(m[0], {})
    f= open(path+m[1]+'.txt', 'r')
    for line in f:
        search_str= "my_name"
        if line.startswith(search_str):            
            linename = line.split(' ',2)[1].strip()
            key= get_name_part(linename)                       
            val[key] = val.get(key, 0) + 1
```

You can simplify your code by using `collections.Counter` and `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict
import os

maindict = defaultdict(Counter)

for m in result:
    counts = maindict[m[0]]
    with open(os.path.join(path, m[1] + '.txt'), 'r') as f:
        search_str = "my_name"
        counts.update(get_name_part(line.split(None, 2)[1])
            for line in f if line.startswith(search_str))
```

Comment: Thank you my problem is solved. For some reason I forgot to mention this.